# Excel VBA – How to create AND dump hash of arrays complex structure?

Tags: excel, vba, macos, perl

I am from perl background and learning Excel-VBA. In perl, we can use Data::Dumper to get the dump of data structure.

Here is the example from perl:

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $hash={};
$hash->{key1} = [ 1, "b", "c" ]; # the value stored against key1 here is an array
$hash->{key2} = [ 4.56, "g", "2008-12-16 19:10 -08:00" ]; # the value stored against key2 here is an array
my $hash2={1=>['one','ONE']}; # this is a hash
$hash->{key3}=$hash2; # the value stored against key3 here is a hash

print Dumper($hash)."\n";
```

It produces following output:

```
$VAR1 = {
         'key2' => [
                     '4.56',
                     'g',
                     '2008-12-16 19:10 -08:00'
                   ],
         'key1' => [
                     1,
                     'b',
                     'c'
                   ],
         'key3' => {
                     '1' => [
                              'one',
                              'ONE'
                            ]
                   }
        };
```

As I mentioned earlier, I am new to Excel-VBA and learning it so please bear with me in helping me reach to the answers of below questions:

1. Is there something similar to perl’s Data::Dumper in Excel-VBA?
2. How do I create a structure exactly similar to above (i.e. $hash) in Excel-VBA using Scripting.Dictionary object? How do I iterate over that structure and retrieve a value stored against the key? Does this kind of structure support 'exists', 'remove', 'add' etc etc methods?

Comment: Can you keep your question to a single specific point? This question requires multiple responses.

Comment: This is a question pertaining to "Excel-VBA" only. I am expecting answers in "Excel-VBA" itself.

Comment: I think the main issue here is that he comes from a Perl world where 'all' problems can be solved in a oneliner, but in vba the solution may be 10-100 linkes of code, and include many many issues.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a built in mechanism that will do what you are asking. You would have to create a "keyedArray" class which implements the methods that you want. Figuring that out would put you solidly up the VBA learning curve.

A good place to start would be http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx

If that doesn't help you, say so in the comments - I may have some time later to put a brief example together.

Comment: I had checked out that URL earlier and that is how I came to know about Scripting.Dictionary object. It would really help if you put together the code in Excel-VBA to create the hash I've shown in my question. And also it would help if you could show me how to iterate over that structure and retrieve the value stored against the key.

Comment: This is NOT a freecode. What have you tried? You cannot expect people to write code for you on this site.

Comment: If you wish to ask the simpler sub-question of "how do I [use] a hash?" or "how can I iterate over these collections?" in VBA, you need to search for answers to these questions yourself and IF AND ONLY IF you have **tried and failed to answer your own question**, then post a single specific question on that topic detailing what you have tried - with examples of the code you have written so far and an explanation of exactly what you think isn't working.

Comment: What have I tried? The answer is I am not able to make a head or tail of it. I have read material on Scripting.Dictionary and could not find / google or put to use the code out of my own knowledge and that is why I posted it as a question here. Instead of educating me in this, you can go ahead and vote for close of this question, if you think so. Please do not get into a word battle with me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You may have one of three needs:

1. Interactive Debug - then add a breakpoint in the debugger, use the Add Watch in vba, and expand the structure iteractively
2. Get the data to a text file for some post treatment -try to look for xml or json exporter
3. Get the data exactly as you show, to import e.g. with Safe into Perl. - then you need to write a recursive procedure yourself.

The latter will be quite difficult, as most vba-structures (unless you make them yourself), have cylcles. (like children => [ ... ], parent => FIX).

VBA Collections does not give you enough support so Dictionary is what you need. (remember to Tools->References to "Miscrosoft Scripting Runtime")

The following is not pefect, but may give you a start

```
Option Explicit ' aka use strict
Option Base 0 ' to be close to perl

Sub test()
    Dim c As New Dictionary
    Dim c2 As New Dictionary
    Dim a(10) As Variant, b() As Variant
    a(1) = 1.1
    a(2) = "array item 1"

    ReDim b(0)
    b(0) = 41.9
    ReDim Preserve b(UBound(b) + 1) ' aka push
    b(UBound(b)) = 41.95

    ReDim Preserve b(UBound(b) + 1)
    b(UBound(b)) = 41.96

    '#build a structure
    c.Add item:="val1.2", Key:="key1.2"
    c.Add item:="val1.1", Key:="key1"
    c2.Add item:="val2.1", Key:="key2.1"
    c2.Add item:=42, Key:="key2.2"
    c2.Add item:=42.1, Key:="key2.3"
    c2.Add item:=a, Key:="key2.4"
    c2.Add item:=b, Key:="key2.5"

    'add c2 to c to make it hierarchical
    c.Add item:=c2, Key:="key1.3"""

    Debug.Print vba2perl(c)

End Sub

Function vba2perl(item, Optional indent = 0)
    Dim txt
    Dim Key, I

    Select Case TypeName(item)

    Case "Dictionary"
        indent = indent + 1
        txt = txt _
            & vbCrLf & Space(indent * 4 - 2) & "{"
        For Each Key In item
            txt = txt _
                & vbCrLf & Space(indent * 4) & Key & " => " & vba2perl(item(Key), indent) & ","
        Next Key
        txt = txt _
            & vbCrLf & Space(indent * 4 - 2) & "}"
    Case "String"
            txt = item
            txt = Replace(txt, """", "\""") ' more escaping needed
            txt = """" & txt & """"
    Case "Integer"
            txt = item
    Case "Double"
            txt = item
            txt = Replace(txt, ",", ".") ' if regional, then fix . vs , tbd
    Case "Empty"
            txt = "undef"
    Case "Variant()"
        indent = indent + 1
        txt = txt _
            & vbCrLf & Space(indent * 4 - 2) & "["

        For I = LBound(item) To UBound(item)
            txt = txt _
                & vbCrLf & Space(indent * 4) & vba2perl(item(I)) & ","
        Next I
        txt = txt _
            & vbCrLf & Space(indent * 4 - 2) & "]"
    Case Else
        Debug.Print "No Handler for type: " & TypeName(item)
    End Select

    vba2perl = txt
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks much! This has indeed given me some direction. Can you also show as to how I can get the individual value like "array item 1" OR 42.1 from the dictionary c? The reason why I am asking this is because in Function vba2perl, you are iterating entire c, and I was wondering if the code to call the individual value will also run into multiple lines.

Comment: as you see in 
    For Each Key In item
            .... Key & " => " & item(Key)

item("ley1.2") will give you the value of the key (even if it looks like a function call)